# I am trying to fetch all links from a website and clicking one by one on all links

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fetch all links from a website and clicking one by one on all links. While running below code- I am getting total links count correctly but I am not able to navigate on the links. It throws `null pointer exception`.

Refer the code

```
public class Fetch_all_links {

static int count =0;
public static String[] links = null;

public static void main (String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\New folder\\exe\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.msn.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    List<WebElement>all_links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    System.out.println(all_links.size());
    for(int i=0;i<all_links.size();i++){


        links[i] = all_links.get(i).getAttribute("href");
        driver.navigate().to(links[i]);
        System.out.println(count + driver.getTitle());
        count++;
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace, which will help identify the problem. Please add that in question itself. Thanks!

Comment: yes i got the answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You are getting a **`Null Pointer Exception`** because you are parsing the attribute **`href`** through `all_links.get(i).getAttribute("href");` and assigning it to `links` which is of **`String[]`** type. Instead to avoid **`Null Pointer Exception`** you can store all the **`hrefs`** in a **`List<String>`**. Next you can traverse the list and open the individual links as follows:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class Q44985587_links {

        static int count =0;
        public static void main (String args[]) throws InterruptedException
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.msn.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            List<WebElement> all_links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            System.out.println(all_links.size());
            List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(WebElement link:all_links)
            {
            String link_href = link.getAttribute("href");
            links.add(link_href);
            }
            System.out.println(links);


        }
    }
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Yes this solves my problem, thanks for elaborating my mistake